# SQL values are 0, even though they exist

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query some vars in my MySQL db, but for some reasons it returns 0.
Here's the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    session_start();

    $connection = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

    if (empty($connection))
        $error = "Could not connect to Database, please contact an admin with this code: DBE1";


    $tnews = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Test ORDER BY ID DESC");

    while ($news = mysqli_fetch_array($tnews))
    {
        $title = $news['Title'];
        $pimg = $news['PrevImg'];
        $ptext = $news['PrevText'];
        $text = $news['Text'];
        $img1 = $news['Img1'];

        echo "<h1>" + $title + "</h1><br><br>";
        echo "<p>" + $pimg + "</p>";
        echo "<br><p>" + $ptext + "</p><br><br>";
        echo "<p>" + $text + "</p>";
        echo "<br><p>" + $img1 + "</p>";
        echo $title;
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Oh and the result
`00000`

I have another site where almost (var names, echo's, ...) everything is the same, it works there! I have really have no idea what's wrong, does anyone have an idea?

P.S: The DB Connection has empty strings because it has the ip, username, password and db of my database! ;D

Thanks for the help!

Comment: replace all your `+` with `.` - you're probably a JS coder. I doubt you want to do math here ;)

Comment: OMG! Thanks! Not that good at php I guess ;D

Comment: You're welcome. JS `+` concatenate equivalent of PHP's `.` and vice-versa.

Comment: Although you don't seem to be using sessions here, your `session_start()` will fail as you have already outputted html. Move `session_start();` to the aboslute top of your script.

Comment: @jeroen If header is used, yes it would account as outputting before header. But not in this case.

Comment: @jeroen Lordie, *foot in mouth*. Sorry, you are so **right**. Oh, I did initially +1 your comment, I just have my wires crossed lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` is a concatenate operator in JS, use PHP's equivalent, being a dot `.`

Now, as stated in comments, you are outputting content before sessions.

You may get a warning similar to this:

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /path/to/file:3) in /path/to/file.php on line 4

Corrected code, is you still want to use sessions. If not, just remove `session_start();`

**Sidenote:** It is important not to have a space before `<?php` or any other output such as HTML, a cookie or a byte order mark, which will also account as outputting before header.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

    if (empty($connection))
        $error = "Could not connect to Database, please contact an admin with this code: DBE1";


    $tnews = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM Test ORDER BY ID DESC");

    while ($news = mysqli_fetch_array($tnews))
    {
        $title = $news['Title'];
        $pimg = $news['PrevImg'];
        $ptext = $news['PrevText'];
        $text = $news['Text'];
        $img1 = $news['Img1'];

        echo "<h1>" . $title . "</h1><br><br>";
        echo "<p>" . $pimg . "</p>";
        echo "<br><p>" . $ptext . "</p><br><br>";
        echo "<p>" . $text . "</p>";
        echo "<br><p>" . $img1 . "</p>";
        echo $title;
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will signal warnings/errors as shown further up in my answer.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Thank you! I'll be using that! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how that worked out in your other server, but you should be using dots `.` instead of `+` to concatenate strings in php.

```
while ($news = mysqli_fetch_array($tnews))
    {
        $title = $news['Title'];
        $pimg = $news['PrevImg'];
        $ptext = $news['PrevText'];
        $text = $news['Text'];
        $img1 = $news['Img1'];

        echo "<h1>" . $title . "</h1><br><br>";
        echo "<p>" . $pimg . "</p>";
        echo "<br><p>" . $ptext . "</p><br><br>";
        echo "<p>" . $text . "</p>";
        echo "<br><p>" . $img1 . "</p>";
        echo $title;
    }
```

Comment: I'm using C++ most of the time, I guess that's why! ;D Thank you!